# What is real meaning of suiteName in UserDefaults initializer?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I attempting to grasp some kind of unit tests, so we create mock user defaults.

```
class MockUserDefaults: UserDefaults {
var gameStyleChanged = 0
override func set(_ value: Int, forKey defaultName: String) {
if defaultName == "something" {
  someStyleChanged += 1
}
}
}
```

right after in setup() i create

```
mockUserDefaults = MockUserDefaults(suiteName: "testing")!
```

So i confused i can't understand full meaning of suiteName i've read official documentation but it is not clear enough, please help

Comment: you can create your own domain what you may use in your other apps or app-extentions (a.k.a. in your own _app-group_) to share data between them flawlessly. ([_source_](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[suiteName:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1409957-initwithsuitename)is kind of an identifier which helps you create preferences(UserDefaults) store. By using a particular suiteName, you are creating a preferences store, that is not bounded to a particular application (whereas standard UserDefaults are different for every application). Because of this reason, you can create a store, that can be shared between different app/extensions.